# How to specify a full text search index (MySQL) in an Alembic migration?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm using Flask-Migrate for a project in which the target database is MySQL-compatible Aurora.

I added a full-text index to a model using [Menzhuo's SQLAlchemy fulltext search module](https://github.com/mengzhuo/sqlalchemy-fulltext-search):

```
class Post(db.Model, FullText, Serializable):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    __fulltext_columns__ = ('description', 'text')
    id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(256))
    .
    .
    .
```

Now when I used Flask-Migrate to generate the migration, the full text index was not picked up automatically. I am well aware of the fact that Flask-Migrate does not pick *everything* up, and that you have to add a few things by hand to the migration scripts.

For example, I know how to manually insert lines such as

```
op.add_column(...)
op.create_unique_constraint(...)
op.create_index(...)
```

inside of the `upgrade` method in the generated migration. However, when I looked at the [`create_index` documentation for Alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html) I do not see any support for creating a full text index. I see the `unique` parameter for unique indexes, but nothing for the full text index.

So am I missing the way to do this directly in Alembic (perhaps using SQLAlchemy commands)? Or would I have to write straight SQL? I would hate to have to do the latter, and I've never done that before. If that is necessary, how does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Alembic documentation on [`create_index()`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_index) we find that

> - ****kw** – Additional keyword arguments not mentioned above are dialect specific, and passed in the form `<dialectname>_<argname>`. See the documentation regarding an individual dialect at [Dialects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/index.html#dialect-toplevel) for detail on documented arguments.

and then in MySQL dialect documentation under ["Index Prefixes"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#index-prefixes):

> MySQL storage engines permit you to specify an index prefix when creating an index. SQLAlchemy provides this feature via the `mysql_prefix` parameter on [`Index`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Index):
>
> ```
> Index('my_index', my_table.c.data, mysql_prefix='FULLTEXT')
> ```

Given the above your Alembic migration should define the index like so:

```
op.create_index(..., mysql_prefix='FULLTEXT')
```

Comment: Well done! I had not noticed how to connect FULLTEXT to the dialect-specific kwarg. This worked perfectly.

Comment: NB: New in version 1.1.5.